# Dell UPS Management Software (ULNM) Shutdown Script Execution Failure

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2008-r2, ups, plink

I got a Dell Server (PowerEdge R420) and a QNAP NAS (TS-412-U) connected to the UPS (Dell 1000W Rack),
the ULNM Software is installed at the Server, the UPS is hooked up to the Server via USB.

In the case of a shutdown event, i want to run a .bat File that is shutting down the NAS via plink prior to the Server shutdown, the .bat File looks like this:

```
C:\shutdown\plink.exe admin@192.168.1.10 -batch -pw xxxxx -m C:\shutdown\nas.shutdown
shutdown.exe -s -t 30
```

nas.shutdown contains this:

```
halt
```

If I run the .bat File directly on the Server via Remote Desktop the Script shuts down the NAS, then shuts down the server, everything alright.

If I execute the Script via ULNM Shutdown Event, a server shutdown in 1 Minute will be initiated and executed but the NAS shut down wont, the plink part seems not to be executed.

[image: ULNM Shutdown Event Assistant]

If I send the Scripts Output to a log file, it stays empty, no error messages or any kind of output.

```
C:\shutdown\plink.exe admin@192.168.1.10 -batch -pw xxxxx -m C:\shutdown\nas.shutdown > C:\shutdown\test.log
shutdown.exe -s -t 30
```

Anybody got a simmilar problem or a solution to my problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was accepting the fingerprint, I did this with my user account but not with the account that executed the shutdown command initiated over the web-interface.

(-batch just surpresses the prompt, not answears it neither negative or positiv...)

To resolve the Problem, its possible to pipe in a y like this:

```
y | C:\shutdown\plink.exe admin@192.168.1.10 -pw xxxxx -v halt
```

Or use a privat key with the matching public key entered into the authorized_keys file on the NAS.